# How to receive value of radiobutton groups on c#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have code in html:

```
<form runat="server"> 
       <table>
           <tr>
               <td>
                   From Date:
               </td>
               <td>
                   <input type="text" runat="server" id="txtDate" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD"/>
               </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>
                   Show Data:
               </td>
               <td>
                   <input type="radio" id="rbShowDataYes" name="chShowData" value="1" checked="checked"> Yes
                   <input type="radio" id="rbShowDataNo" name="chShowData" value="0"> No
               </td>
           </tr>
...
</form>
```

In c#, when I try to reach `txtDate.Value`, it is working, but `rbShowDataYes.Checked` not working saying that `rbShowDataYes` is not in the current context. Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

```
string value=chShowData.SelectedItem.Value.ToString();


bool isChecked = radioButton1.Checked;
if(isChecked )
  value=radioButton1.Text;
else
  value=radioButton2.Text;
```